# How to set default Radio button in Angular when created with an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Basically I create my radio buttons based on items returned from the server. There are not always values returned, in which case the user adds a new one:

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td><input type="radio" name="item" ng-model="selected" ng-value="{{item}}" ng-change="getNewOtherStuff(item)"/></td>
</tr>
//close table stuff

<div class="halfMarginTop">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add)">Add Row</button>
</div>
```

How do I set the first item in the list to be the checked one by default, when there is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just init it in your JS controller once you received the data.

```
if($scope.items.length > 0) $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
```

hope it helped.